# Disabling form auto submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I am trying to build an image upload interface which submits the form automatically as soon as choosing a file from the file browse window. This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="avatar.php" method="post" id="avatarForm">
  <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ8mN2ibS1RFAfbliQ_QjEPmnVFY272SpjSCSz9uDIfj4wUvM39Rw" width="100px"/>
  <input onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();" type="file" id="avatar" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

and this is how my JS looks like:

```
$("input[type='image']").click(function() {
        $("input[id='avatar']").click();
});
```

Problem is as soon as I click image input which triggers #avatar, file browser is being opened but the form automatically being submitted without allowing me to choose a file from the window.

What is wrong here?

Comment: what browser do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<input type="image">` is a graphical submit button, so when you click it, it will automatically submit the form. Here's the documentation on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/image. If you want to stop the form from submitting, you need to cancel the default action of the click. So, your code would be this:

```
$("input[type='image']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("input[id='avatar']").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem. Here it seems to work. It doesn't submit the form when I open the file browser, until I choose an image and close the file browser. (note it doesn't post after it either but that's because of a javascript error that is not related to your problem. When you copy this code to an empty html it should work)

```js
$("input[type='image']").click(function() {
        $("input[id='avatar']").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="avatar.php" method="post" id="avatarForm">
  <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ8mN2ibS1RFAfbliQ_QjEPmnVFY272SpjSCSz9uDIfj4wUvM39Rw" width="100px"/>
  <input onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();" type="file" id="avatar" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

Comment: That is exactly how my code looks like. But, when I click on the image, "browsing window" is being opened but the page is being redirected without my control (Chrome). In IE, waits for the browse window, but again it is being redirected no matter if I make a change or just cancel the window.

Comment: But does it work here, when you click on Run code snippet? Strange, here in Chrome it works.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same problem. It seems there's a bug in Chrome. The form is submited automatically and I am using pure Javascript.